# What is the easiest way to store passwords and access_keys/secret_keys on the Jenkins machine?

Tags: security, jenkins

What is the easiest way to store passwords, SSH private keys and AWS access_keys/secret_keys on the Jenkins machine?

I have moved all passwords out of the Git repositories, but some access_keys/secret_keys have now been made available as environment variables so that the pipelines still work.

I'm looking for a simple, easy, not too complex-solution that will give us a basic security for storing secrets that's more secure than saving passwords as environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use credentials plugin to store credentials in Jenkins. Once you have this plugin, you should be able to add credentials of following type in Jenkins and use the credential id in your pipeline:

[image: credential types]

---

**Examples and usage:**

- *Username with Password type*:

  [image]

> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent any
>     environment{
>         SOME_CREDS = credentials('some_cred_id')
>         //Credential can directly be used in the url ex:
>         PYPI = "https://${SOME_CREDS}@artifactory.com/artifactory/api/pypi/PyPi/simple"
>     }
>     stages {
>         stage('Init') {
>             steps {
>                 script{
>                      //User and password env variables will be populated automatically:
>                      println "user: ${env.SOME_CREDS_USR}"
>                      println "pass: ${env.SOME_CREDS_PSW}"
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

- *SSH Username with private key*:

  **Another way** to use credentials is using sshagent (but then credential id must be of kind "**SSH Username with private key**" and
  "**SSH Agent plugin installed**"). Ex:

  [image]

> ```
> script {
>     sshagent(['some_cred_id']) {
>         sh(script: 'git fetch origin master')
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can define credentials of the following types:

- "secrets"
- "Username with password"; and
- "SSH Username and private key"

Make sure to set the ID and Description fields to something "human readable".

Once these are defined they can be accessed from a Jenkinsfile in a secure way like so:

**"Username with password" type credential**

`withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "<human-readable CredID>", passwordVariable: 'p_password', usernameVariable: 'p_username')]) {
    //do something useful with "${p_username}" and "${p_password}"
}`

What this does is gets the Jenkins Credential and puts its components into **named** environment variables on the fly that in turn can be referred to and used inside the `withCredentials` clause.